# Other uses for Korean salted shrimp

Tags: flavor, asian-cuisine

I purchased a jar of tiny Korean salted shrimp to make kimchi.  Since I only use a teaspoon or so at a time for the kimchi, I wondered if there were other (Korean or otherwise) creative uses for these salted shrimp.

Comment: Is Korean salted shrimp the same as dried+salted shrimp and powdered shrimp found in Hong Kong, Taiwan or Southeast-Asia? I know people sprinkle it onto their noodle soup or stir-fry, or even into their a'la BLT sandwich. Is it also popular in Japan? I have seen it with pink speckles - is that pepper-jacked shrimp bits or just the colour of the shrimp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kimchi is probably the biggest use I can think of, but there's also steamed egg: http://www.maangchi.com/recipe/egg-side-dishes

Otherwise, 새우젓 is frequently used as a dipping sauce for foods like marinated pigs' feet (족발) and blood sausage (순대). Also added wherever appropriate for a little umami punch.